# How do I get a current content from URL field (or title field) in a workflow programmatically and convert to string?

Tags: 2010, development, visual-studio

I get a wrong value from field.

```
 private void onWorkflowActivated1_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
{

    SSPFieldUrlValue fieldValue = new SPFieldUrlValue(SPContext.Current.Item["Repository"].ToString());
    string linkTitle = fieldValue.Description;
    string linkUrl = fieldValue.Url;          


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need generate a SPitem, instancing from a workflowproperties.

```
        //Currente item
        int item = onWorkflowActivated1.WorkflowProperties.ItemId;
        SPItem current =  onWorkflowActivated1.WorkflowProperties.Item;    
        //Get url from field
        SPFieldUrlValue fieldValue = new SPFieldUrlValue(current["Repository"].ToString());
        string linkTitle = fieldValue.Description;
        string linkUrl = fieldValue.Url;
```